# twitter API can not search specific hashtag #StaySafeNashville

Tags: api, search, twitter

I’m trying to fetch all @NESpower tweets with hashtag #StaySafeNashville. I can individually search for @NESpower tweets with no issues. However I get no tweets back when I also search for #StaySafeNashville.

I have tried:

- ../1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3ANESpower%20%23StaySafeNashville
- ../1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23StaySafeNashville
- ../1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23staysafenashville

Comment: v1.1 Search API goes back a max of ~7 days